# PhpStorm path mapping when using Docker via WSL2

Tags: php, docker, phpstorm, development-environment, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm using Docker based php environment (using Laradock) via WSL2 on Windows 10 (Home Edition), and I'm trying to add remote interpreter to PhpStorm.

Everything is working well, but I have a problem with path mapping between WSL and Docker, I tried even UNC path and mounted drive, and still not working.

- PhpStorm 2020.2
- Windows 10 Home Edition
- Docker Desktop 2.3 with WSL2 Backend
- WSL mounted on Network Drive (Z:)

When I try to run test.php, I'm getting the error "File not found", it seems that PhpStorm is using bad path mapping in configuration.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What file are you trying to open? The path on in a browser is `/pstorm/test.php` while in IDE you're trying to open just `/test.php`.

Comment: pstorm is project folder which is opened in PhpStorm, the problem is that PhpStorm does not map correctly between WSL and Docker

Comment: @DibraDev did you ever fix this? I am not having the same problem. Looks PHPStorm's runner should mount my project on WSL to the container but when I log into the containers bash there's no mounted project.

Comment: @l3fty No, I'm currently using phpunit, composer and npm from CLI